# How can I view what privileges I have?

Tags: support, privileges

I am having trouble seeing where on my status page to click to see what privileges I have earned. I have stumbled onto it before, but I forget how I did it. Where should I go to see this?

I did some poking around, and searched the questions, but came up empty. Surely this is a duplicate, but even the related questions the system shows as I write this are no help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a link to the [privileges page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/privileges) in the drop down menu that appears when you hover over your username (on the main site):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Yannis. I usually ignore the popup and just click my name, because my main page has most of that information, plus a lot more. How would I go about suggesting privileges be made easier to find (like one of the main tabs), or has that idea been killed long ago? :)

Comment: @RandallCook Well, you can always try a feature request. The link is a bit out of the way, and ignoring pop ups is understandable.

Comment: I had no idea the link existed there... I've always found the page by typing `/privileges` to the end of the main site url

Comment: nice screen capture with your publicist badge.  ;-)